# How can I map multiple sub domains to folders in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My case is that I have to subdomains connected/verified with Firebase hosting.

I want to map both of subdomains to different files in different folders.

For example:

app.example.com -> app/index.html
admin.example.com -> admin/index.html

Comment: If it's not listed in here, you probably can't do it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites  If you have a feature request for something you aren't able to do, please file it here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: ahan. Well its supposed to be a basic feature in any hosting environment. Anyway, I will do as you suggest. Thanks

Comment: @user3601213 did you happen to find the answer? I'm also looking for this

Comment: @LuisCabrera Its not possible right now. I don't know if they have added yet